# Pre save a slug on creation results in a 'LogEntry' object has no attribute pre_save

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I am trying to auto generate a slug on creation of my object in Django.

My method is to use the `pre_save` signal, using the `@receiver` call.

When I create a new entry in my Django admin, I get `'LogEntry' object has no attribute 'title'`.

I made an admin model that looks like this:

```
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'is_visible')
```

I have the following `model.py` code for my Country object:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        return Country.objects.filter(is_visible = True).order_by('title')

    @receiver(pre_save)
    def country_presave_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        instance.alias = slugify(instance.title)
```

How would I modify my code so slugs are always automatically created on creation of my objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the `sender` model to the `@receiver` decorator:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Country)
def country_presave_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

In this case the callback will only be called when an instance of `Country` is saved.  Without the `sender` argument the callback will be called for **all** models.

Comment: Hey :-) When I add sender=Country, I get: "NameError: name 'Country' is not defined" - any idea what I am doing wrong?<

Comment: Answer was I had to indent method outside the class, so it's a method of models.py, and not a member of the class. Thanks so much for your help @catavaran !